# QGIS query comparing the value of two fields doesn’t work

Tags: qgis, filter

I try to filter my layer in QGIS comparing the value of two fields. Somehow, this code doesn’t work:

```
( "Field1_integer" <>  to_int( "Field2_string"))
```

If I use the same code for selecting by expression, it works. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What should happen when you execute the expression? What does "this code doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Sorry for the imprecise question. It should only display the features which have different values in `Field1` and `Field2`. E.g. `Field1 = 611`, `Field2=’612’` it should be displayed. `Field1=611`, `Field2=’611’` it should NOT be displayed. What happens now is that just no feature is displayed.

Comment: When filtering QGIS send the query to the data provider to be evaluated but when selecting by expression QGIS work with the data already loaded in memory and use QGIS syntax and fonction. As different data provider may have different syntax requirement or a different set of fonction implemented  than QGIS this explain why the same query may work in some context but not in other. For your query to work in filtering context you need to check the data provider capabilities.

Comment: @J.R  I’ve never heard about data provider capabilities. How can I find out the capability of my data provider and how I have to construct the query? Can I set the data provider to be the same as the loaded data?

Comment: You just need to take into account in witch format your data is stored and check witch syntax apply in this format (for exemple sqlite database dont have a to_int() fonction, you need to use cast() )

Comment: I suppose instead of `<>` you could try `NOT LIKE`.

Comment: I tested the `NOT LIKE` but it didn't work. I now tested only to convert the string field. And this seems to generate an error.  I tested `to_int()`,`int()`,`integer()`,`to_integer()` . I also tested to convert `Field1` to string. It also generates an error. The datasource is a gpkg polygon utf-8 dataset `Field1` is type real, `Field2` type string. Might it be that it is not possible to convert in the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Selecting by expression (or using the expression builder)

When you select by expression (or use the expression builder anywhere in QGIS) you are working "inside" QGIS and should use QGIS syntax and fonction so the proper syntax (as you tested it) is :

`"FIELD_REAL"<>to_int("FIELD_STRING")` (note that `"FIELD_REAL"<>"FIELD_STRING"` will also work)

---

### Filtering (or using the query builder)

When creating a filter you are sending a query to the data provider that will interpret it, so you need to use the proper syntax and fonction for this data provider.

As you work with data in a gpkg the proper query are :

`"FIELD_REAL"<>CAST("FIELD_STRING" as integer)` or `"FIELD_REAL"<>CastToInteger("FIELD_STRING")`

As gpkg doesn't need to explicitly convert string you may use :

`"FIELD_REAL"<>"FIELD_STRING"` (note that this query will also work in the expression builder anywhere in QGIS)

---

If that didn't work properly you may need to check that your field string contain only number (no character, no trailing space,...)

And lastly you should by able to use `<>` or  `!=` indifferently in any of the above expression

Comment: All of the three queries work perfectly. Thanks a lot!
I never expected that it would also work without even converting the string. Is there a website that explains the differences between the different data providers? And maybe also one which lists all the possible functions for gpkg queries?

Comment: I don't think you will find a site that reference all data provider (there are many database system and even a single system may behave differently between version), for gpkg as it's based on sqlite database you may look at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html (not an really easy read...)